# Curl mechanism, inside the expressjs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, curl, axios

I am new to most of these concepts, so I apologize if this question is trivial.

I have a script that makes an HTTP POST request in Curl, for sending json file data .

```
curl https://XXXX.zendesk.com/api/v2/channels/voice/tickets.json ^  
-d @C:\Users\Agent\Desktop\json.json ^   -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u AAAAA@BBBBB.com/token:99dd6ghxsdrf85fgYdHWb33VYCZXI35fg8w13pfL -X POST
```

i need to use the mechanism for making HTTP requests of Curl in my code expressjs,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/index.html',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+'index.html');

})

app.get('/express_get',function(req,res) {
   response ={
       firstname : req.query.firstname,
       lastname: req.query.lastname,
       Email: req.query.email
   };
    console.log(response);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})


var server = app.listen(8000,function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App running on http://127.0.0.1:8000')
})
```

but unfortunately i don't know how to make it !!

so the questions are:

**1:**

> **-d @C:\Users\Agent\Desktop\json.json**
>    in the Curl code, is the file that i want use it , it contain data, what do you think about replace it by (**JSON.stringify(response)**) in the expressjs code !!

**2:**

and how can i do the same work of curl inside my expressjs code !!!!

Any help, any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe look at this : https://curl.trillworks.com/ and express-curl module https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-curl

Answer (score 1):

you want to request *https://XXXX.zendesk.com/api/v2/channels/voice/tickets.json* from one of your express route ?

For that there is Node.js HTTP built-in module (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), which offers the possibility to do a POST request to an host.

There is an example just below on how to use it

```
// From https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

const postData = querystring.stringify({
  'msg': 'Hello World!'
});

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

You will need to read your JSON file (with Node's FileSystem module) and write it to `req` after stringifying it :)

Comment: thank you sir for your answer, but i want to execute Curl request and write it inside my expressjs code.. how can i do it !!